# Converting categorical to the percentage

Tags: data, categorical-data, normalization, numerical

How do I convert the categorical value to the percentage?|

I have this asset wellness data:

```
Poor: 3
Warning: 27
Good: 120
```

How do I convert it to the percentage based on categorical

```
Asset Healthiness Overall: 79.9%
```

Where 100% means overall asset is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
df['asset wellness percentage'] = (df['asset wellness'].value_counts(normalize = True)) * 100
```

The above code will count the number of `Poor`, `Warning` and `Good` from your data and then `normalize` will divide the counts by the total number of rows.

You can keep that which is normalized data and most of the models works well on such data (linear models) but if you still want the `percentage` then multiply it by 100.